Using Python, Flask, Celery and Redis a task containing more than one group is incapable of calling a sub task with chains on it
@celery.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def process_ml_model_dataset(self, dataset_serialized, media_serialized, ml_model_serialized, collection_name, n_factor):

    if n_factor == 1:
    result_group = group(process_ml_model_dataset_factor_x.s(dataset_serialized, media_serialized, ml_model_serialized, collection_name, n_factor))
else:
    # tasks = [process_ml_model_dataset_factor_x.s(dataset_serialized, media_serialized, ml_model_serialized, collection_name, i) for i in range(1, n_factor+1)]
    result_group = (group(process_ml_model_dataset_factor_x.s(dataset_serialized, media_serialized, ml_model_serialized, collection_name, i) for i in range(1, n_factor+1)))
    # tasks = []
    # for i in range(1, n_factor+1):
    #     tasks.append(process_ml_model_dataset_factor_x.s(dataset_serialized, media_serialized, ml_model_serialized, collection_name, i))
    # result_group = group(*tasks)

result = result_group()

while not result.ready():
    time.sleep(60)

@celery.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def process_ml_model_dataset_factor_x(self, dataset_serialized, media_serialized, ml_model_serialized, collection_name, factor_x):
result_chain = chain(
    process_ml_model_chunk.s(None, 1, dataset_serialized, ml_model_serialized, first_chunk_pickle, collection_name, factor_x))

reader_second_chunk = FILE_HELPER.csv_reader_chunked(
    MEDIAS_UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST + "/" + str(media_serialized["id"]) + "/" + media_serialized["file_name"],
    columns_header, DATASET_CHUNK_SIZE, DATASET_CHUNK_SIZE)
for i, chunk in enumerate(reader_second_chunk):
    result_chain |= process_ml_model_chunk.s(i + 2, dataset_serialized, ml_model_serialized, pickle.dumps(chunk),
                                             collection_name, factor_x)

In the following short sample of code my code / environment cannot perform this tasks. In this example I am requesting that a group of tasks containing chains of tasks on it perform some job, I get the following output on my worker:
worker-1  | [2024-04-03 09:42:23,143: INFO/MainProcess] Task src.tasks.dataset_full_ml_process.process_ml_model_chunk[d3c55d4c-2c1e-48e5-927f-50dce7ac6738] received
worker-1  | [2024-04-03 09:42:23,210: INFO/MainProcess] Task src.tasks.dataset_full_ml_process.process_ml_model_chunk[26af7b45-d1fd-41f6-88c3-04b2f3dd9f6a] received
worker-1  | [2024-04-03 09:42:23,273: INFO/MainProcess] Task src.tasks.dataset_full_ml_process.process_ml_model_chunk[0314e273-a66b-493a-88e6-6ae81f30cb5e] received

But the tasks are never performed. Working with celery seams easy to apply to any circumstance, I have read the in docs for solutions, search a lot of stackoverflow threads and so far no chance of performing such tasks.
The code I provided is just a sample but I have the project base on such approach: docker-flask-example  by Nickjj
I have tried so far celery versions 5.3.6 and 5.4.0rc2.
My Celery setting are pretty strait forward:
REDIS_URL = os.getenv("REDIS_URL", "redis://redis:6379/0")

# Celery.
CELERY_CONFIG = {
    "broker_url": REDIS_URL,
    "result_backend": REDIS_URL,
    "include": [
        "src.tasks.dataset_full_ml_process"
    ],
}

As suggested by Nickjj in docker-flask-example  the docker-compose.yml part of the worker is like this:
  worker:
<<: *default-app
command: celery -A "src.app.celery_app" worker -l "${CELERY_LOG_LEVEL:-debug}"
entrypoint: []
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpus: "${DOCKER_WORKER_CPUS:-0}"
      memory: "${DOCKER_WORKER_MEMORY:-0}"
profiles: ["worker"]

PS: Everything works when I request the task process_ml_model_dataset with n_factor == 1, which makes a group task of one task only.


Having a task wait for the result of another task is really
inefficient, and may even cause a deadlock if the worker pool is
exhausted.

You can read more about it here.
Your process_ml_model_dataset is waiting for the result of other celery tasks (a bunch of process_ml_model_dataset_factor_xs). While process_ml_model_dataset running it's waiting for other tasks, and "take" the worker for itself, thus, other tasks cannot run (if you don't have enough free workers).

The best thing you can do is check the result_group status from your Flask server.
If you wish to stay with a Celery task, you can use the retry mechanism. That way, the task will try to get the result, and if they aren't ready, it will stop running and retry in X seconds (x number of retries you want).
That way the worker will be freed to handle any sub-tasks you wish. Just run the flow and store the UUID of the result_group. Then use it in a new task to see if it is ready.

Here is a pseudo code:
@celery.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False, max_retries=10)
def process_ml_model_dataset_status(self, task_id):
    num_retries = int(self.request.retries)
    if num_retries == 0:
        # optional: do your thing only in the first run if needed
        
    result = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)
    if not result.ready():
        raise self.retry(countdown=60). # retry in 60 seconds
    return result.get()


@user2278362 does it answer your question?

Looking at it right now. Due to research constraints i could not i have done it earlier.

first of all thanks for the reply. @ItayB your considerations were of value and using chains instead of groups i could mitigate the problem. But i could not understand the usage of your pseudocode. Should i use process_ml_model_dataset task_id in result = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)or after if num_retries == 0: i could not understand thanks in advance.

@user2278362 the idea is that you shouldn't wait for a Celery task result within (another) Celery task. You should remove the while & sleep. You can return the UUID and check if it's ready every X seconds. Another way might be https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords
